# How to construct an RDD or DataFrame dynamically?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm doing some pre-processing on a bunch of data. Each line has the following schema

```
<row Att1="...." Att2="..."  Attn"...." />
```

However not all the attributes exist in all the rows. That is some rows might have only three attributes while some other have five, etc. Besides, there is no way attribute indicating how many attribute exist within each row.

I would like to form an RDD or DataFrame (prefrable) and run some query on the data. However I can't find a good way of splitting each row. For example, splitting by space not work. I only need a few attributes in my processing. I tried to use pattern matching to extract 4 attributes that exist in all the row as follows but it fails.

```
val pattern = "Att1=(.*) Att3=(.*) Att10=(.*) Att11=(.*)".r
val rdd1 = sc.textFile("file.xml")

val rdd2 = rdd1.map {line => line match {
    case pattern(att1,att2,att3,att4) => Post(att1,att2,att3,att4)
  }
}

case class Post(Att1: String, Att3: String, Att10: String, Att11: String)
```

p.s. I'm using scala.

Comment: This is too broad to answer here. Also, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I updated my post with what I did so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is less of a spark problem than it is a scala problem. Is the data stored across multiple files?

I would recommend parallelizing by file and then parsing row by row.

For the parsing I would:

1. Create a case class of what you want the rows to look like (This will allow the schema to be inferred using reflection when creating the DF)
2. Create a list of name/regex tuples for the parsing like: ("Attribute", regex)
3. Map over the list of regex and convert to a map: (Attribute -> Option[Value])
4. Create the case class objects
5. This should lead to a data structure of List[CaseClass] or RDD[CaseClass] which can be converted to a dataframe. You may need to do additional processing to filter out un-needed rows and to remove the Options.

Comment: Thanks, No data is stored in just a single file. but could you show me some sample code for these steps as I'm new to both spark and scala.

Comment: Could you have a look at what I have done and tell me what I've done wrong?